# How do I convert this to spherical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, integration, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

The task is to set up the integral in spherical coordinates. The given integral is: $$\int_0^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}}^{\sqrt{8}} z^2-x^2-y^2 dzdydx $$
I'm new to spherical coordinates so I get confused as to what my bounds for $\phi$ would be? I'm getting $\phi=[0,\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})]$ Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This figure showing the integration region should help:

[image]

$- \pi/2 \leq \theta \leq + \pi /2$

$0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{8}$

$0 \leq \phi \leq \tan^{-1} (1/\sqrt{2})$

Comment: How was $\phi=\frac{\pi}4$ solved for? Because when I try to convert $z=\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}$ into spherical, what I get is $\phi=\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$. I can't seem to get an exact value like $\frac{\pi}4$?